# How to measure ESR

Tags: capacitor, measurement, esr

I have a bunch of capacitors but no clue of what ESR they have. Is there a way to measure the ESR? Can I set up a test circuit to measure it?

Comment: At the 30kft level, you need to measure the impedance, then subtract the reactance.

Comment: For repair testing purposes of ordinary high-value power supply capacitors (especially those for mains frequency filtering), measuring |Z| at 100kHz with a 50\$\Omega\$ output signal generator and 'scope may be enough (even in-circuit if you use a low voltage). In general, it may get difficult, particularly for very low ESR caps (m\$\Omega\$)

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would stick it on my  [LCR bridge](http://www.thinksrs.com/downloads/PDFs/Manuals/SR715720m.pdf), set it for 120Hz or 100kHz (as appropriate) and the appropriate equivalent circuit, and read off the C and R from the digital displays. That's pretty accurate down to about 20m\$\Omega\$ ESR. This is how it works:

[image]

The connections to the DUT are made Kelvin-style with four coaxial cables.

The complex (both real and imaginary parts) of ratio of the voltage/current gives the complex impedance, from which the C and ESR can be calculated. The former are found by demodulating (multiplying) the V and I using \$V_S\$ (real) and \$V_S\$ phase shifted by \$\pi\over 2\$ (imaginary) and measuring the four resulting voltages after a low-pass filter.

If you were making a bridge specifically for ESR it could be optimized for that purpose- a lower minimum Rs in particular.

Comment: Thank you for the input. However it seems to be a bit above my level of experience. I found [this](http://geoffg.net/Measuring_ESR.html) "simple" method to charge the capacitor through a serie resistor with 1us, 1KHz pulses and measure the voltage over the capacitor. It might not be rocket science but at least in the ball park...

Comment: @MaxKielland Indeed that method I covered in my comment. It measures |Z| so it will be in the ball part if the C is large and ESR is large. It's not a universal answer, but if it works for you, go for it.